# How to debug failed NetCore AWS Elastic Beanstalk deployment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an DotNet Core AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment which has started failing to deploy. The environment waits up to 10 minutes for the healthcheck to pass, but consistent gets "403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.".

I've RDP'd to the environment and the folder `C:\inetpub\AspNetCoreWebApps` is empty. In working environments, this contains the code.

I've tried redeploying the entire environment and deploying a package from a week ago which was previously fine. Additionally, I've tried deploying using the AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio and by uploading a package rather than using CodePipeline. All of these actions result in the same behaviour.

I'm struggling to find any logs which indicate why the code isn't being deployed to the environment. Requesting the last 100 lines doesn't contain anything useful and I can't find any deployment logs on the filesystem. In the pulled logs there is no `AWS.DeploymentCommands` log file.

The environment is configured to deploy as rolling with batch +1. As such, it is a new EC2 which is being written to.

What is the next step in debugging the cause of the failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to diagnose the problem - a public file referenced in the ebextension folder had been deleted. The log file I was looking for was in `C:\cfn\log\cfn-init.txt`.